# NI USB-6008 issues

Tags: windows, visual-c++, nidaqmx

I am trying to run the sample C program that came with my NI USB-6008 DAQ card. I am trying to run the "ContGen-ExtClk.c" example. I get the following error when I build the program:

```
DAQmx Error: Requested value is not a supported value for this property. The property value may be invalide because it conflicts with another property.
Property: DAQmx_SampTimingType
Requested Valeu: DAQmx_Val_SampClk
You Can Select: DAQmx_Val_OnDemand

Task Name: _unnamedTask<0>

Status Code: -200077
End of program, press Enter key to quit
```

If anyone is familiar with the USB-6008, I would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a hardware issue with how many samples can be sent over the analog out channel... dunce move.